# Equilibrium of rods and stress

Tags: forces, torque, equilibrium, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

Reading through *Theory of Elasticity, Landau & Lifshitz*, I got stuck in the *The equations of equilibrium of rods*, on page 82. The part I do not understand is the following:

"We denote by $\vec{F}$ the resultant internal stress on a cross-section. [...] If we regard the two adjoining cross-sections as the ends of the element, a force $\vec{F} + \,d\vec{F}$ acts on the upper end, and $-\vec{F}$ on the lower end; the sum of these is the differential $\,d\vec{F}$."

Why do the forces on the top and on the bottom have opposite directions?

**Additional Information**

I consulted Lautrup's *Physics of Continuous Matter* section on the subject. In the situation that a vertical rod (aligned with the $z$ axis) bends in the $yz$-plane, it draws the following diagram of forces:

[image]

Where $K_y$ and $K_z$ are the forces per unit length in the $y$ and $z$ directions, respectively. The same question arises: why do $F_y(z)$ and $F_y(z+\,dz)$ have opposite directions? And the same goes to $F_z(z)$ and $F_z(z+dz)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just Newton's 3rd law in action.

Take this simpler example of a 1D rope and look at the forces acting on a small section of length ${\rm d}x$. Also, look at an adjacent section.

[image: fig1]

The first segment gets tugged to the left by the part of the rope on its left size by an amount $T(x)$, and to the right by the part of the rope on the right side by an amount $T(x+{\rm d}x)$.

Now consider the next segment, and you need to apply an equal and opposite force of $T(x+{\rm d}x)$ directed to the left of this segment in addition to the force $T(x+2{\rm d}x)$ directed to the right.

The only thing that is erroneous in the diagram shown in the book is that all forces need to be shown in a positive manner like I have done above, following the convention that positive tension forces stretches the rope.

The book has the forces directed to the left shown as $-T$ which assigns a global direction to the force (positive to the right, and negative to the left) which might complicate things when it comes to calculating stretch.

Comment: Thank you! I now understand why $F_z(z)$  and $F_z(z+dz)$ point in opposite directions. However, I don't quite see how this applies to $F_y$. Moreover, what could be the origin of a force in the $y$ direction (besides external forces)?

Comment: For a string/rope, the tension is going to be tangent to each segment and that might include two components in plane (y,z) in your post. This requirement does not exist for beam segments that can support side loads. These forces do not originate from the segment, but they are just passing through from where the external loads are applied to where the structure is supported (the so call load path). If indeed the loading has components along both _y_ and _z_ directions then the internal loading in the structure would also do.